# How do I flip a video in the VSE?

Tags: transforms, video-sequence-editor, video

I'm having many difficulties with the video editor.
One issue is that I can't figure out how to right a video that is sideways or upside down.
How can this be done in Blender?

Comment: This video worked for me https://youtu.be/hfo-DRGvkgo

Answer (score 11):

In the properties panel <kbd>N</kbd>, of the Video Sequence Editor there are some setting for the active strip. Scroll down to the *Filter* heading and there are two check boxes to flip the strip on the X and the Y axes.
[image: Video Sequence Editor strip controls for flipping]

---

Your other option is to add a transform strip, then use that to rotate your clip.

With the clip you want to rotate selected add a new transform strip by either going to the Video Sequence Editor header *Add* > *Effect Strip* > *Transform*, or by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

Then in the same properties panel as in the first part, you will find the settings for the transform strip. 
[image: transform strip settings]

Answer (score 7):

Let me extend the answer from @David, the transformation strip rotation works but doesn't correct the aspect of the image. If you want to rotate **and keep the original aspect** then follow these steps. I'd love it if anyone has an easier way of doing this...

1. Note the original x and y video dimension, for this example let's assume 1080 x 1920
2. Add the transform strip with a rotation as per @David's answer
3. In the properties for the render change the **Render Dimension** to swap the x and y

[image]

4. In the transform bar add the **scale** parameters entering the formula based on your originally noted dimensions, so "1920/1080" in the first field and "1080/1920" in the second field

[image]

Comment: PS the user ping feature does not work in questions or answers, only comments. [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/278094)